# Updating repository with changes i created, in local project?

Tags: git, repository

I'm beginner in github, and created `new repository`.

I wanna update all changes i did on the project, i try the following command:

```
git pull origin master
```

but in the repository there are no changes, and try the command again get the following:

```
 From https://github.com/mahmoud7796/starterTest
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

what should i do, i wanna all changes show in the repository

Comment: In which repository? It's unclear whether you're trying to push your local changes remotely or pull the remote changes locally.

Comment: I think you mean to `push` instead of `pull`, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: i'm sorry i want to push changes i created to the repository, it's right, it supposed write push not pull, it works now thanks so much